# Try catch using a function for negative integers

Tags: c++, exception

So basically I am trying to get it to stop repeating. If I enter numbers correctly it works fine. If I enter negative numbers which are not allowed and needs a try-catch exception it keeps repeating and won't stop asking for numbers. 
All I have is this source file for the code and I am trying to make a function for main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void gcd(int x, int y);

int main()
{
    int x;
    int y;
    cout << "Please enter two integer values" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
    gcd(x, y);

    return 0;
}

void gcd(int x, int y)
{
    int gcd;
    int s = 0;
    while (s == 0)
    {
        try
        {
            if (x < 0 || y < 0)
                throw 1;
            else
            {
                s == 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (int x)
        {
            cout << "Wrong negative input please type in two Positive integers" << endl;
            cin >> x >> y;
            continue;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= x && i <= y; i++)
    {
        if (x % i == 0 && y % i == 0)
            gcd = i;
    }
    cout << "The gcd of x: " << x << " and y: " << y << " is: " << gcd << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is not how you use exceptions. Read a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Comment: You should verify the inputs before passing them to the function.

Comment: Also, there is a well known efficient gcd  algorithm, described by Euclid almost 2,500 years ago.

Comment: And the function should return the gcd, not print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your function `gcd()` to be called with negative values, throw a `std::invalid_argument` exception. It is not the business of `gcd()` to request user input. Validate the input in `main()` before you call `gcd()`.

```
#include <limits>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

int gcd(int, int);

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    while (std::cout << "Please enter two positive integers: ",
           !(std::cin >> x >> y) || x < 0 || y < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Input error :(\n\n";
        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }

    std::cout << "The gcd of x: " << x << " and y: " << y << " is: " << gcd(x, y) << "\n\n";
}

int gcd(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < 0 || y < 0)
        throw std::invalid_argument("No negative arguments to gcd(), please :(");
    return y == 0 ? x : gcd(y, x % y);
}
```

Comment: Or `gcd` can take unsigned type :-)

Comment: Have you ever tried to error-check the extraction of an `unsigned` from a stream?

Comment: As you said, not the job of `gcd` to request/validate user input. so `main`can stay unchanged. (but indeed behavior of `std::cin >> u` is sad [Demo](https://ideone.com/Ka076n)).

Comment: Thank you that works and I see where the code was going, but does anyone know where one could find a list of all exceptions we could use?

Comment: @DerekLanger you can throw every type you like. but here you are: [<stdexcept>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/)

Answer (score 0):

You can (and perhaps should) remove the logic from `gcd` function and instead place it where you get your input from user, that is, in `main`. Also, state the requirements up front. For example:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int x;
    int y;
    cout << "Please enter two positive integer values" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
    if (x < 0 || y < 0)
    {
        cout << "Wrong negative input please type in two Positive integers" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    gcd(x, y);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, you can place assertions in `gcd` to enforce no negative values get in:

```cpp
void gcd(int x, int y)
{
    assert(x >= 0);
    assert(y >= 0);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `assert`ions will only work in debug builds. when `cin >> x` or `cin >> y` fail you're in a world of shiiiiet.